# Find defined data from file and use as variable

Tags: linux, bash, loops, curl

I have some POST curl request to multiple creating profiles. Next step I send GET request to get all created profiles and save results to *.txt files. Then I would like to find in this file only data with **ID** and use it to make multiple updates (via PUT request) or multiple delete for all profiles.

```
#!/bin/bash
token="Authorization: Bearer 1bcXamxE5sSpT8A-7L_fJIWA"
url="http://ad44fcfa01aad11e9naws.com/api/v0.1/scanprofiles"
curl -X GET $url -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "$token" > get.txt

q=15

name=3_Ubuntu_internal

ports=1042

h=12
m=41
for ((i = 0; i < q; i++))
 do
    data='{"target":{"scan_type":"internal","ip_range":"10.142.0.2-10.142.0.5","ports":"'${ports}'"},"name":"'$name$i'","run_immediately":"False", "schedule": {"utc_offset": 120, "time": "'${h}':'${m}'",  "start_date": "2019-02-26T10:13:00+02:00","recurrence":{"recurrence_type": "daily","data":{"spike":"1"}}}}'
    ports=$((ports+1))
    m=$((m+1))
    if [ "${m}" -eq "60" ];
      then 
      h=$((${h}+1)) && m=41
    fi
    if [ "${h}" -eq "15" ];
      then 
      h=12
    fi
    if [ "${ports}" -eq "1238" ];
     then
     ports=1042
    fi

    echo "${data}"
    curl -X POST $url -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "$token" -d "$data"
 done
```

simple of the answer from GET request:

```
{
        "status": "ready",
        "last_run_time": "2019-02-27T10:44:34+00:00",
        "found_cert_count": 3,
        "id": "0a3c62a9-2f61-4e78-802a-2a6b31e43af8",
        "tenant_id": "840ccfeb-ee3b-451f-aaf9-7a4fe8f3cbee",
        "target": {
            "ip_range": "10.142.0.2-10.142.0.5",
            "scan_type": "internal",
            "ports": "1045"
        },
        "name": "3_Ubuntu_internal3",
        "scan_run_id": "be263639-cbaa-44e5-a249-f2c38f12c80f",
        "run_immediately": "False",
        "schedule": {
            "utc_offset": 120,
            "time": "12:41",
            "start_date": "2019-02-26T08:13:00+00:00",
            "recurrence": {
                "recurrence_type": "daily",
                "data": {}
            }
        },
        "next_run_time_utc": "2019-02-28T10:41:00+00:00"
```

So I need to get all **"id"**: "**0a3c62a9-2f61-4e78-802a-2a6b31e43af8**" and use it (only GUID) on the next PUT or DELETE requests in the loop

Last working code is:

```
  #!/bin/bash
token="Authorization: Bearer XVbusTNtmjAYFoAJQ"
url="http://us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/api/v0.1/profiles/"
url_run="http://us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/api/v0.1/profiles/run"
local="http://localhost:62183/api/v0.1/profiles/"
local_run="http://localhost:62183/api/v0.1/profiles/run"
q=10
name=New_UbuntuX
host=(15.11.38.43 15.11.49.89 15.11.188.24 15.11.19.83 15.20.155.82 15.20.14.27 15.11.14.31 15.11.14.23 15.11.19.17 15.11.29.47)
data1=""
curl -X GET $url -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "$token" > get.txt
id=($(sed -En '/"id"\s*:/ { s/.*"id"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)".*/\1/; p; }' get.txt)) 
printf "%s\n" "${id[@]}"
#next request should be delete all found profiles by id
for i in "${id[@]}"#I know that seems not properly correct just paste it to 
#show how I'm think that should be in there
  do
   curl -X DELETE $url"${id[@]}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
  done
"$token"
for ((i = 0; i < q; i++))
 do
    data='{"target": 
 {"scan_type":"external","host":"'${host[$i]}'","ports":"143- 
 184"},"name":"'$name$i'","run_immediately":"False"}'
    curl -X POST $url -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "$token" -d 
"$data" #create external profiles with defined host
 done
 curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" $url_run -H "$token" -d 
"$data1" #run all profiles
```

Comment: `jq` is your best bet. If you are desperate and can't do anything else, a carefully constructed regex could likely handle it : `id=$( sed -En '/"id"\s*:/ { s/.*"id"\s*:\s*"([^"]+^C.*/\1/; p; }' get.txt )` ... but there's a lot of opportunity for error there. YMMV, ***caveat scriptor***.

Comment: @PaulHodges as I understand command sed should help me, but this line `id=$( sed -En '/"id"\s*:/ { s/.*"id"\s*:\s*"([^"]+^C.*/\1/; p; }' get.txt )` is little bit hard for me and I got an error `sed: -e expression #1, char 44: unknown option to `s'`. Can you separete this line step by step? Also I tryed to find place for missed ')' I guess not succed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, I recommend a real JSON parser, but -
First, apologies. my copy/paste was corrupted. It has an embeded ^C-break, and no trailing paren or quote.
mea culpa.

Breaking it down:

```
id=$( sed -En '/"id"\s*:/ { s/.*"id"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)".*/\1/; p; }' get.txt )
```

`id=` is standard variable assignment.
`$( ... )` runs it's contents and returns the stdout, which here would be assigned in the `id=$( ... )` construct.

So let's look at the `sed`.

`-E` uses extended pattern matching, so (for example) I don't need to backslash the parens to make them metacharacters.
`-n` says not to print anything unless I explicitly request it.

the program:

`/"id"\s*:/ { ... }` says to execute the commands between the braces when the line matches the pattern between the slashes.
the pattern is a literal `"id"` followed by any number(0 or more) of whitespace characters (`\s*`) followed by a colon.

`s/.*"id"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)".*/\1/; p;` is the command list to run on matching lines.
the substitution is `s/<find>/<replace>/;`
In this case, the  is `.*"id"\s*:\s*"([^"]+).*`; broken down,
`.*` matches any number of "any" character. See the manual for details. This throws away everything before the part we care about.
`"id"\s*:\s*"` says to find `"id"`, zero or more whitespace, a colon, another zero or more whitespace, followed by a double-quote character
`([^"]+)` is the important part - the parens say to remember what's between them; `[^"]+` means one or more non-double-quote characters.
`".*` throws away the quote at the end of the data and any/all trailing characters behind that.

At this point, the matched data ought to be the value between the quotes identified by the `"id":`, and should be storefd in `\1`.
The  part is the `\1`, so the whole line ought to have been trimmed to just the part you want.

The `p;` say to print the now-trimmed line, so the id ought to be stored in the variable.

Make sure there isn't more than one id in your data that matches those conditions....

> ## EDIT

Putting them in an array. A dup'd the line a few times.

```
$: id=( $( sed -En '/"id"\s*:/ { s/.*"id"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)".*/\1/; p; }' get.txt ) )
$: printf "[%s]\n" "${id[@]}"
[first-0a3c62a9-2f61-4e78-802a-2a6b31e43af8]
[second-0a3c62a9-2f61-4e78-802a-2a6b31e43af8]
[3rd-0a3c62a9-2f61-4e78-802a-2a6b31e43af8]
[4th-0a3c62a9-2f61-4e78-802a-2a6b31e43af8]
[5th-0a3c62a9-2f61-4e78-802a-2a6b31e43af8]
[last-0a3c62a9-2f61-4e78-802a-2a6b31e43af8]
```

> ## Next Edit

c.f.:

```
for i in "${id[@]}"
do  curl -X DELETE $url"${id[@]}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
done
"$token"
```

First, aren't you getting an error at `"$token"`?
It should probably be saying something vaguely like

```
bash: Authorization:: command not found
```

Second - `for i in "${id[@]}"` sets `i` to each `id` in turn, but then you never use it in your loop. Instead, you use

```
curl -X DELETE $url"${id[@]}" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

which is not going to do what you want.

Look at this example:

```
$: x=( a b c )
$: for i in "${x[@]}"
>  do echo "Right:  id is '$i'"
>     echo "Wrong:  id is '${x[@]}'"
> done
Right:  id is 'a'
Wrong:  id is 'a b c'
Right:  id is 'b'
Wrong:  id is 'a b c'
Right:  id is 'c'
Wrong:  id is 'a b c'
```

What you have done is the wrong one. Try it this way:

```
for i in "${id[@]}"
do  curl -X DELETE "$url$i" -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
done
```

That's probably still not quite going to work till you get the authorization right, though, so...

```
declare -a stdArgs=( -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "$token" ) 
for i in "${id[@]}"
do  curl -X DELETE "$url$i" "${stdAtrgs[@]}"
done
```

See if that's better.

Comment: Really great job @Paul Hodges ! Thanks a lot! It works and finds the clear GUID but as you said "_Make sure there isn't more than one id in your data that matches those conditions_" was found last of all id and I need to find all of them from the response and use them to make multiple update or multiple delete, so I think is need to create another one simple loop.

Comment: I'm just returned to this question. And unfortunately variable as array doesn't work properly. I tried different methods but always get the last element. Maybe you have any idea why? Thanks a lot @Paul Hodges

Comment: Would have to see your code.
Add it in as an edit at the bottom of your original post.

Comment: ditto. Let me know. :)

Comment: Hi @Paul Hodges! Thank for your answer. Try it now. But about $token it works well because I need to use token for every request.

Comment: Sound strange but still doesn't work properly. Still get back only last element doesn't matter what use $i or ${id[@]}

Comment: I know you need the token, but your code isn't *using* it - it's just trying to execute it all alone on a line by itself, which seems like it should break. And what's in your id list?

Comment: In this DELETE request `curl -X DELETE $url"${id[@]}" -H "Content-Type: application/json"` I just forgot to add it here but you can see that I use it in the POST and PUT requests so the same I planned to use and in the DELETE request. About id list, I can get only last element as I said and of course I can execute script several times to delete all profiles))) but I don't think that it's a good way. You can try to use the answer from simple of the GET request to see how many elements return.